# Json parsing with gson not working

Tags: android, json, gson

This is my JSON string:

```
[{"BranchID":1,"SecurityCode1":13,"SecurityCode2":14,"PrintHeight":10,"PrintWidth":10,"Active":true}]
```

This is Code I am using to parse the JSON:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<List<Setting>>() {
}.getClass();

String json =  ServiceHelper.getJSON(response); 
List<Setting> list = (List<Setting>) gson.fromJson(json, t); 
    //list is null which it souldnt
```

This is the Setting class, Entity is ORMDroid entity class:

```
public class Setting extends Entity {

@Column(name = "id", primaryKey = true)
@SerializedName("BranchID")
public int BranchID;

public int securityCodeLPK;
public int securityCodeSDK;

@SerializedName("PrintHeight")
public int PrintHeight;

@SerializedName("PrintWidth")
public int PrintWidth;

@SerializedName("Active")
public String Active;

@SerializedName("SecurityCode1")
public String SecurityCode1;

@SerializedName("SecurityCode2")
public String SecurityCode2;

public Setting(int BranchID, int height, int width, String active, String securityCode1, String securityCode2) {
    super();
    BranchID = BranchID;
    PrintHeight = height;
    PrintWidth = width;
    Active = active;
    SecurityCode1 = securityCode1;
    SecurityCode2 = securityCode2;
}

public Setting () {
    super();
}

}
```

It seems to be OK, but list after gson.FromJson is null. What's wrong with this code?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getType()` instead of `getClass()`.

```
Type t = new TypeToken<List<Setting>>() {}.getType();
```